# How to stop interval from observable

Tags: rx-java

I am new on rxjava, i want to execute a polling task every 2 seconds for 50 times, also it may terminate if some condition meet in the task, i am trying to use `Observable.interval` but i found there is no way to terminate it except for throwing exception, is there any other operator to meet my goal ? 
BTW this functionality work as API to provide observable object so i can not control the subscriber and termination by unscribe.

```
Observable.interval(timeout, interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.flatmap(task - > task)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I guess `Observable.takeUntil(stopPredicate)` or `Observable.takeWhile(predicate)` can help you:

```
Observable.interval(timeout, interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS) 
.takeWhile(val -> val < 42)
```

Here observable will terminate on 42th attempt

Comment: What is timeout, is this max time to execute or is it the initialDelay to emit first value?

Answer (score 5):

You can stop an `Observable.interval` using `takeUntil` as follows:

```
Observable.interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .takeUntil(new Predicate<Long>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(Long aLong) throws Exception {
                    return aLong == 10;
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Consumer<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Long aLong) throws Exception {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Tick: " + aLong);
                }
            });
```

In this example, after 10 seconds, observable will stop.

Comment: can we add a callback to this stop event? i.e. is it onComplete? I guess I'm looking for something like doOnUnsbscribe() or doOnComplete()

Answer (score 1):

The code below will produce the following output:

```
Starting interval..
Next tick is: 1
Next tick is: 2
Next tick is: 3
Next tick is: 4
Next tick is: 5
Interval complete
```

If you uncomment this line: "// if( t==3 ) dispose();" it will only print the following:

```
Starting interval..
Next tick is: 1
Next tick is: 2
Next tick is: 3
```

the code:

```
         Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).take(5).subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Long>() {
        @Override public void onStart() {                
            // do whatever might be needed here to run once before
            // the interval begins
            System.out.println("Starting interval..");
        }
        @Override public void onNext(Long t) {
            System.out.println("Next tick is: "+t);
            // if( t==3 ) dispose();
        }
        @Override public void onError(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        @Override public void onComplete() {
            // will be called once when all 5 ticks are completed
            // will NOT be called if dispose() has been called
               System.out.println("Interval complete");
        }
    });
```